# Add Magento Existing project to Github repository

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, github

I want to link my staging and live site.My workflow is as follow
First i have done changes locally then upload it to staging and live site manually.Now i want to automate this process.I need to done changes locally then upload it to new branch.Then want to take pull at staging and live site.I have take backup of staging site and set it locally.I am confused in these steps can someone give me a direction in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the process for setup existing project to git.

- Create a repo on git.
- use git init command inside magento folder
- git remote -v
- git fetch --all
- git checkout master
- use git add . to add files in git (make sure you are not adding vendor or other files which should not be in git , please check .gitignore for that)
- create statging branch
- create new branch from master using git checkout -b
- work on that and commit on feature branch
- create PR of feature branch with staging
- once task tested create new PR with master
- git checkout master
- take pull of master
- create tag using git tag -a  -m "Description"
- push tag using git push --tags

Now take checkout of this tag on server

Deploy always tags instead of direct master branch , by this way if you want to switch between your versions it will be easy.

You can join our channel as we are going to create a video for git sooner to explain git in depth.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBtRV9tdH-ghtDsjRPcD6pg

Comment: after a commit and marge to master can we revert back to previous master version?

Comment: you can try revert feature in PR, I didnt tried it so not sure about this but you can try I hope it work as u expected.